# C# Sending files with sockets. I want to send file between 2 client through server

Tags: c#, sockets

My server doesn't receive file. Can someone help me please? Also I want to know how to make server send file to the other client once it recieved file from one client

Client.cs

> ```
> private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         FileDialog fDg = new OpenFileDialog();
>         if (fDg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
>         {
>             FTClientCode.SendFile(fDg.FileName);
>         }
>     }
>     class FTClientCode
>     {
>         public static void SendFile(string fileName)
>         {
>             try
>             {
>                 IPAddress[] ipAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses("host");
>                 IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(System.Net.IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 5656);
>                 Socket clientSock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream,
> ```
>
> ProtocolType.IP); 
>                       string filePath = "";
>                       fileName = fileName.Replace("\", "/");
>                       while (fileName.IndexOf("/") > -1)
>                       {
>                           filePath += fileName.Substring(0, fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
>                           fileName = fileName.Substring(fileName.IndexOf("/") + 1);
>                       }
>
> ```
>                 byte[] fileNameByte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(fileName);
>                 if (fileNameByte.Length > 850 * 1024)
>                 {
>                     return;
>                 }
>
>                 byte[] fileData = File.ReadAllBytes(filePath + fileName);
>                 byte[] clientData = new byte[4 + fileNameByte.Length + fileData.Length];
>                 byte[] fileNameLen = BitConverter.GetBytes(fileNameByte.Length);
>
>                 fileNameLen.CopyTo(clientData, 0);
>                 fileNameByte.CopyTo(clientData, 4);
>                 fileData.CopyTo(clientData, 4 + fileNameByte.Length);
>
>                 clientSock.Connect(ipEnd);
>
>                 clientSock.Send(clientData);
>
>                 clientSock.Close();
>
>             }
>             catch (Exception ex)
>             {
>             }
>
>         }
>     }
> ```

Server.cs

> ```
>         public static string receivedPath = @"M:\Music\";
>         private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
>         {
>
>                 backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
>         }
>
>         FTServerCode obj = new FTServerCode();
>         private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
>         {
>
>             obj.StartServer();
>         }
>
>         class FTServerCode
>         {
>             IPEndPoint ipEnd;
>             Socket sock;
>             public FTServerCode()
>             {
>                 ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 5656);
>                 sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.IP);
>                 sock.Bind(ipEnd);
>             }
>             public void StartServer()
>             {
>                 try
>                 {
>                     sock.Listen(100);
>
>                     Socket clientSock = sock.Accept();
>
>                     byte[] clientData = new byte[1024 * 5000];
>                     int receivedBytesLen = clientSock.Receive(clientData);
>
>                     int fileNameLen = BitConverter.ToInt32(clientData, 0);
>                     string fileName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(clientData, 4, fileNameLen);
>
>                     BinaryWriter bWrite = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(receivedPath + "/" + fileName,FileMode.Append));
>                     bWrite.Write(clientData, 4 + fileNameLen, receivedBytesLen - 4 - fileNameLen);
>                     bWrite.Close();
>                     clientSock.Close();
>                 }
>                 catch (Exception ex)
>                 {
>                 }
>             }
> ```

Comment: Because of your empty `catch` blocks, all useful exception information is unavailable for you and you have to guess, what is going wrong. You should use exception information first, e.g. `Trace.WriteLine(ex)` and add a `TextWriterTraceListener` to your client and server application configuration files. If you see, that the client sending works, check the firewall settings on the server side, too.

Comment: TCP is *streams of bytes*, not *messages*. Congratulations, you know how long the name of the file is (if you were lucky enough to get at least 4 bytes in that call to `Receive`). However, you're by no means guaranteed that the call to `Receive` also returned the entire set of bytes making up the file name *nor* that every byte from the file were also included. `Send` and `Receive` are *not* matched 1-1 by TCP.

Comment: Tks man. Can you help me with how you can make server to send the file to the other client once it received the file?